# If I create an inline keyboard markup with a button, is it possible to show another inline keyboard by pressing on that button

Tags: python

```
import telebot
import config
import random

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    img = open('static/welcome.gif', 'rb')
    bot.send_video(message.chat.id, img)

    # keyboard
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data='TEST1')
    item2 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data='TEST10')
    item3 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data='TEST10')
    item4 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("",'')
    item5 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("קהילה ראשית", '')
    item6 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data='TEST4')
    item7 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data='TEST5')
    item8 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("ביקורות", callback_data='TEST6')
    item9 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("♻️שיתוף♻️", callback_data='TEST7')
    item10 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("בדיקת סוחר", callback_data='TEST8')
    item11 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("❓מי אנחנו❓", callback_data='TEST9')

    markup.add(item1, item2 ,item3 ,item4 ,item5 ,item6 ,item7 ,item8 ,item9 ,item10 ,item11)


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "שלום, {0.first_name}!\nטלקוקאין נוסדה בשנת 2020 , על ידי צוות מתכנתים מהשורה הראשונה  בדגש על אבטחת הנתונים ❗️.\nאנחנו כאן בשביל להנגיש סמים בכל הארץ.\nאוהבים TeleCocaine רכישה מהנה.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)





@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'TEST9':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'אז בקצרה...Telecocaine ישראל מתעסק בתיווך\nבין סוחרים ללקוחות אנחנו דואגים ללקוחות\nסוחרים ברמה הגבוה ביותר שרק אפשר לדמיין\nשירות לקוחות ומענה אנושי 24/7☎️\nעזרה לכול נושא או בעיה יש למענכם צוות\n‍מנהלים אדיב אמין ומסור\nושירותי בוטים מאובטחים ')







    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))

# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the inline keyboard, use the [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) method. And if you want to change the text as well, the [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) method will help you change both.

```
...
new_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
new_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('New button', callback_data='new_one'))

# Changing only inline keyboard
bot.edit_message_reply_markup(
    chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
    message_id=call.message.message_id,
    reply_markup=new_markup
)

new_text = 'New text'

# Changing the message
bot.edit_message_text(
    text=new_text,
    chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
    message_id=call.message.message_id,
    reply_markup=new_markup
)
...
```

Comment: I mean when i'm press on the inline button ( open MORE inline button )

Comment: @NewNew I understand you, I said that **[Updating messages](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages)** methods like **editMessageReplyMarkup** and **editMessageText** will help you. _You can realise it by example above!_